# Create Swing Components in a loop and access them

Tags: java, swing, loops

I need to read a configuration file and put the data (it consists of key-value-pairs) into some textFields I have to create dynamically in a JFrame.
After that I want to modify the textFields and save the changes to the file again.

What I have so far:

```
        FileConfiguration fileConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration(new File("xesfile.properties"));

        Iterator<String> keys = fileConfig.getKeys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String singleKey = keys.next();

            //for the case that a key has multiple values
            if (fileConfig.getProperty(singleKey).getClass().equals(ArrayList.class)) {
                ArrayList<String> blaArray = (ArrayList<String>) fileConfig.getProperty(singleKey);
                for (int i = 0; i < blaArray.size(); i++) {
                    this.keyLabel = new JLabel(this.nameKeyLabel + this.count);
                    this.entityLabel = new JLabel(this.nameEntityLabel + this.count);
                    this.keyTextField = new JTextField();
                    this.keyTextField.setName(this.nameKeyTextField + this.count);
                    this.keyTextField.setText(singleKey);
                    this.entityTextField = new JTextField();
                    this.entityTextField.setName(this.nameEntityTextField + this.count);
                    this.entityTextField.setText(blaArray.get(i));
                    this.count++;
                    this.configFrame.add(this.keyLabel);
                    this.configFrame.add(this.keyTextField);
                    this.configFrame.add(this.entityLabel);
                    this.configFrame.add(this.entityTextField);
                    this.configFrame.revalidate();
                    this.configFrame.repaint();
                    this.configFrame.pack();
                }
            //for the case a key has a single value
            } else {
                this.keyLabel = new JLabel(this.nameKeyLabel + this.count);
                this.entityLabel = new JLabel(this.nameEntityLabel + this.count);
                this.keyTextField = new JTextField();
                this.keyTextField.setName(this.nameKeyTextField + this.count);
                this.keyTextField.setText(singleKey);
                this.entityTextField = new JTextField();
                this.entityTextField.setName(this.nameEntityTextField + this.count);
                this.entityTextField.setText((String) fileConfig.getProperty(singleKey));
                this.count++;
                this.configFrame.add(this.keyLabel);
                this.configFrame.add(this.keyTextField);
                this.configFrame.add(this.entityLabel);
                this.configFrame.add(this.entityTextField);
                this.configFrame.revalidate();
                this.configFrame.repaint();
                this.configFrame.pack();
            }

        }
```

As you see the TextFields are created again and again in every pass of the while-loop. But I need to access the textFields I created in the first pass of the loop for the example.
Thought if I would access the TextFields with `getName()` they would be returned, but that's not the case.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your TextField in a Map with key as name and value as TextField object itself. You could later access it using:

```
TextField textField = map.get("myField");
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really simple but I'm quite new to java programming. Marked your answer as correct. Don't understand why I was downvoted though...

Comment: Glad it helped you.. yeah even i don't understand why it's down voted.

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple

```
// In loop
1) Create the component.
2) Add it to an Generic ArrayList
3) You can also attach an actionListener to the component in loop if you want.
// Out of loop
4) Iterate the ArrayList and access the desire component.
```